# Connection between Mongodb and UR5 Nodes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Recently I have been working with the Universal Robot Stack, When I tried to test the demo.launch file present ur5_moveit_config package, Everything works fine but then I tried to check the Inter-connectivity between different nodes by typing.

```
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

This Command opens the rqt window and displays the Inter-connectivity between all the Nodes. However the mongodb_wrapper Node does not seem to be connected to any of the Nodes. I would like to understand, as to how one can utilize this database?  Any one who has worked on this with other Robots are also requested to share the details. As I understand, This db is used to store Planning information! Please Correct me if I am Wrong.

Thanks and Regards,

Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105336/connection-between-mongodb-and-ur5-nodes?/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the mongodb_wrapper is used through service calls and not topics. (Which would make sense in my opinion...)

These will not be visible in rqt_graph.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2013-11-27**:
Thank you for Replying @Ben_S, would it be possible to access mongodb like other databases? I am wanting to understand the relationship between 'Planning' a Pose and How it is 'Stored and Retrieved'?.